# ¿Habilitar la reproducción de video HTML5 en Android WebView?

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

Es una aplicación simple de reproducción de videos y quiero hacerlo por html5 pero me da la pantalla gris y no reproduce, este es mi codigo:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView= findViewById(R.id.webViewVideo);

    WebSettings webSettings= webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/video.html");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo habilitar la reproducción de video dentro de webview?

Contenido del HTML

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js@7/dist/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://unpkg.com/silvermine-videojs-quality-selector@1.1.2/dist/css/quality-selector.css" rel="stylesheet">

<video id="videojs" class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" autoplay muted fluid="true" >

      <source src="https://video1.getstreamhosting.com:1936/8058/8058/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
 <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
 </p>
</video>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js@7/dist/video.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var player = videojs('videojs');

   </script>
```

Comment: El video esta embebido y es youtube? Puedo ver el contenido de video.html ?

Comment: @Elenasys ya agregue el contenido del HTML

Comment: Creo que puede ser por los permisos del android manifest, lo has mirado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad el problema lo esta causando el `WebCromeClient`, en este caso no es necesario ya  que estas tratando de cargar una url, lo cual no es necesario.

```
webView= findViewById(R.id.webViewVideo);

WebSettings webSettings= webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

/*webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});*/
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/video.html");
```

de esta forma cargarás tu página y la reproducción del video funcionará sin problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, una consulta mas por favor, como puedo habilitar para que al presionar el boton de fullscreen del reproductor se cambie a pantalla completa