# ¿Como manipulo los reproductores de video de las paginas webs que cargo en mi webview con una instancia de exoplayer?

Tags: java, android-studio, webview, mediaplayer

Necesito manipular los reproductores de video de una pagina web X con exoplayer en mi app android a travez del webview.

Asi tal cual lo hace UC Browser(Un navegador para Android). Que cada vez que vas a reproducir un video en una pagina web cualquiera, el navegador lo detecta e incrusta su propio reproductor de video integrado, remplazando el diseño y funciones del reproductor.

Necesito hacer lo mismo pero con un reproductor simple de exoplayer.

Soy desarrollador de android hace un par de años pero es mi primera vez en este tema de manipular webs a travez de WebView.

Yo tengo mi WebView y suponiendo que en el siguiente enlace de transimisión

https://nosequewea.tk/dtvc?get=Ly9kdHZvdHQtY2JjLmFrYW1haXplZC5uZXQvZGFzaF9saXZlXzExNDcvbWFuaWZlc3QubXBk&key=OThiZjFkNTEwY2I0NTE0NTk0MmU1ZDRjMWQ1ZjIxMWQ=&key2=ZDZkNTE4OTQ5Y2Y3MzRjM2UwMzMyOGRkYTViNDU5NjY=

quiero que se visualize mi reproductor personalizado de exoplayer en el webview. ¿Como deberia hacer?

Answer (score 0):

En realidad, lo ideal es usar la vista de `Exoplayer` y ahí reproducir tu video:

```
 <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/idExoPlayerVIew"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp" />
```

Si lo que deseas es reproducir tu `Exoplayer` dentro de un `WebView`, El objeto `Exoplayer` tendría que cargarse dentro de una página Web y esta página ser cargada dentro de un `WebView`, aunque dudo esto funcione, definitivamente no es la solución correcta.

**Debes implementar nativamente el reproductor `Exoplayer` para ser usado en una app Android**

**Debes [implementar nativamente el reproductor `Exoplayer` para ser usado en una app Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer?hl=es-419)**, para los sitios web deberías usar un reproductor HTML5/JavaScript, revisa:

[**¿Habilitar la reproducción de video HTML5 en Android WebView?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394562/habilitar-la-reproducci%C3%B3n-de-video-html5-en-android-webview)

te sugiero revisar el ejemplo de `Exoplayer` en una aplicación Android:
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer